# wcslen returns bad length when using -fshort-wchar

Tags: c, linux, wchar

Source code:

```
const wchar_t* x = L"abc";   
printf("%d\n",wcslen(x));
```

I compiled this with `g++ -fshort-wchar xxx.cpp -o xxx`, and I get `15` as the result. Why?

Comment: Is it C or C++? You tagged with C, but use g++ to compile

Answer (score 4):

The gcc documentation warns:

```
 *Warning:* the `-fshort-wchar' switch causes GCC to generate code
 that is not binary compatible with code generated without that
 switch.  Use it to conform to a non-default application binary
 interface.
```

Presumably, the `wcslen` you are linking to was generated with normal-length `wchar_t`s, and is consequently counting until it finds a `(regular_wchar_t)0`. The `L"abc"` generated with short `wchar_t`'s will not be terminated with a regular `wchar_t`, so `wcslen` will continue running through random memory until it finds one.

Comment: To cope with the windows wchar only takes 2 byte, so must use the-fshort-wchar, but the length of the string is wrong with wcslen

Comment: @billwang: then you need to make sure you are using the `msvcrt` runtime library instead of `glibc` (or some such: I'm just guessing about your compilation environment since you haven't provided any information at all about it).

Comment: @billwang MinGW(-w64), "GCC on Windows", doesn't need any special switches, it is C ABI compatible with MS DLLs. Don't mess with the ABI unless you know what you are doing and have no alternative. I don't see why you would need this.

Comment: @rubenvb:I porting the windows APP to linux, currently in the Red Hat (OS) environment, must be maintained and the windows using the same wchar, wcslen current difficulties are the result of the calculation is wrong, I do not know how to solve ?

Comment: @billwang: You'll have to come up with some way to make what you're porting happy with longer `wchar_t`s, or you'll have to come up with a runtime environment which uses short `wchar_t`s. The standard library on your runtime environment won't work with short `wchar_t`s, and the problem is not restricted to `wcslen`.

Comment: @bill file and network encoding should be platform agnostic. Otherwise you're in for a load of trouble. If this is already the case, I don't see why you care about the size of `wchar_t`...

Comment: @rubenvb: Because the Windows AP was completed many years ago, the present work is to add support for Linux running environment, in order to reduce the porting of trouble, so try and windows of the AP the same, if not used wcslen, how to write a new function to calculate the width characters in length

Comment: @billwang: It should be obvious how to write `wcslen`: count the characters until you see a `0`. However, I reiterate, all `w*` functions will fail, not just `wcslen`. Honestly, I don't know what you're trying to do exactly, but the path you're heading down is not a simple one.